# KineticJS shape over image

Tags: image, shapes, kineticjs

I want to draw some shapes over an image.

After the image is loaded and added to the layer, I use the moveToBottom() function, which works for shapes but doesn't seem to work with images.

I've tried to use moveToTop() on the shapes, but still no luck.

Important note: I have to keep them on the same layer, so the obvious solution to put the image in another layer is not an option.

Comment: can you put some of your code in a jsfiddle? I'll be able to help you out then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/hukNL/

This concept shows that layering functions work, so the error is somewhere else in your code.

First of all, you want to be using the newest KineticJS 4.3.1, then you want to make sure that if you are dragging images that you disable putting them in the dragOnTop layer that is now featured in the newer releases. Lastly, if nothing else works, then you could manually debug your code by checking the z-index of each item by using:

```
 .getZIndex()
```

Also, if you would like more help, post some code so others can help you debug it.

Comment: I found a part of the problem. The images are in a Group element which seems to have some very weird behaviour.

img.getParent().getChildren() gives me a list of elements, but img itself isn't one of them, which I find very strange.

I managed to fix it now by moving img.getParent().getChildren()[0] to  the bottom instead of just img. I really don't know why this works, but for the moment I'm happy that it works.